# Magento 2 DI preference priority

Tags: magento2, dependency-injection, interface

I've used DI preferences to set an interface to use a class in my own module e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockManagementInterface" type="MySpace\MyModule\Model\StockManagement"/>
</config>
```

However, there is also a DI preference for this interface in the original core module.

In some cases this works, and others (such as in this case for Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockManagementInterface), it does not - it still uses the original.

What determines which class wins out? If it cannot be determined, how is this a reliable way to do a full class rewrite in the many many cases where Magento 2 has made it impractical to use a plugin or observer?

[Note that I "solved" the above issue by setting a preference for the class Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\StockManagement instead, but this does not allow for direct use of that class such as for composition]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All config files merged in order of module load.

You can change order by add sequence in you module.xml files.

For example

```
<sequence>
    <module name="Magento_Search"/>
    <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
</sequence>
```

means that your module will load after Magento_Search and Magento_Catalog and you will overwrite preferences of these modules

Comment: But how does one handle the case of another module (unknown) coming later and defining its own preference overriding your module's? Do modules have a way of detecting their load order and so on?

Comment: You cannot handle it. It is why we don't recommend use preferences for overwriting core functionality

Comment: Ok thank you. I dont know to what extent we can use "around" clause to override core observes "execute" function though. So a chicken n' egg situation. Been mentioned elsewhere.

Comment: Protip: Execute bin/magento setup:upgrade afterwards for the changes to take effect.